# Address sanitizer: PC is at a non-executable region. Maybe a wild jump?

Tags: c++, debugging, g++, address-sanitizer

My compiled code is faulty and I decided to use address sanitizer to find its problem with `g++` and options `-Og -g3 -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer`.

I used llvm-symbolizer

```
export ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-9
```

```
$ ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1 ./a.out

AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==7296==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000200000039 (pc 0x000200000039 bp 0x000000000001 sp 0x7ffd2b566c48 T0)
==7296==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==7296==Hint: PC is at a non-executable region. Maybe a wild jump?
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer: nested bug in the same thread, aborting.
```

It has no meaningful information that helps me finding the source of the problem in my code

It does not dump the stack trace. What does it mean and how can I find the stack-trace or the location of the dumped addresses?

**update**: Using gdb does not give much more info too

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /media/bin/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Full compilation was performed in 0.005376 seconds.
Code has an error.
No input file is given


==8965==LeakSanitizer has encountered a fatal error.
==8965==HINT: For debugging, try setting environment variable LSAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=1:log_threads=1
==8965==HINT: LeakSanitizer does not work under ptrace (strace, gdb, etc)

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff1eac438 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
54  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff1eac438 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007ffff1eae03a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff72d14be in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5
#3  0x00007ffff72dbe78 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5
#4  0x00007ffff72e0ecf in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5
#5  0x00007ffff72e0f05 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5
#6  0x00007ffff1eb137a in __cxa_finalize (d=0x7ffff752e4a0) at cxa_finalize.c:56
#7  0x00007ffff71ca793 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5
#8  0x00007fffffffdc50 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007ffff7de7e27 in _dl_fini () at dl-fini.c:235
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

Comment: @J... I was expecting address sanitizer does its job right instead of throwing the responsibility to the debugger.

Comment: @J... unfortunately address sanitizer creates no core dump to use gdb on it. (Even though I used `export ASAN_OPTIONS=abort_on_error=1:disable_coredump=0:unmap_shadow_on_exit=1` and `ulimit -c unlimited `).

Comment: I'd at least not drop your frame pointers - these are what you need to get a stack trace.  Could be UB in a VMT offset/pointer - address sanitizer won't catch that.  The crazy pc value is what is causing the 'wild jump' guess.  If not memory corruption then likely a bad method pointer.   Try memory sanitizer also.

Comment: @J..., what ever option I try, I get no symbol.

Comment: Yes, because if it's memory corruption or UB in a pointer variable then address sanitizer cannot find it - that's not what it does.  You'll need to debug or use another tool.

Comment: The downside of an event like this is the actual bug is likely somewhere miles away. Maybe something, stack overflow or rogue pointer or nasal demons, mauled the stack. ASAN is not telling you what caused this most likely because it can't. Maybe UBSAN can.

Comment: @user4581301, it looks like even `-fsanitize=undefined` cannot catch the problem. Maybe I should do a manual binary search on my code.

Comment: GDB isn't that helpful if the stack got smashed because it's counting on the stack NOT being smashed. I would start my inspection here at `_dl_fini () at dl-fini.c:235` and hope it's my code AND the stack hasn't been completely savaged to the point that it's all a lie. But `_dl_fini ()` not "my" code. That shouldn't get called until the program is shutting down. But... that could help narrow down the death zone. Do you have any global variables?

Comment: Under gdb lsan crashes due to unrelated error you need to add `detect_leaks=0` to you `ASAN_OPTIONS` to avoid that.

Comment: @J..., after some efforts, I discovered that my none-void function did not return any value but and the value was not used anywhere else too. After I added some couts, more information start showing up while they should have not impacted the sanitizer. That's weird. The shown error was `ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting double-free on 0x6030000063a0 in thread T0`. When I turned that none-void function to void, it was fixed. But it was strange because the type of function is a pointer. I was expecting nothing to be released. More looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: @ar2015 Show the code, surely there's more to the story.